# Insert an image into a .docx file

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, openxml, docx

I am developing a program that has the feature to dynamically create DocX files. As the title suggests, I am having a problem inserting images into a DocX file. One of the issues, as I see it, is that I am using C# 2.0. (When answering this question, I would like to stress that I do not wish to switch to C# 3.0, so please do not try to persuade me.)
I have taken a look at the MSDN article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx, but when I converted the C# 3.0 code that MSDN uses to C# 2.0, I get a document that does not open, and it gives me the error: "The file Testing.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents," and "No error detail available."

Here is my code:

```
ImagePart ip_Part;
WordprocessingDocument wpd_Doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create("C:\\Convert\\Testing.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
public Testing()
{
    wpd_Doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    wpd_Doc.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
    wpd_Doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();

    ip_Part = wpd_Doc.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
    System.IO.FileStream fs_Stream = new System.IO.FileStream("image.png", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    ip_Part.FeedData(fs_Stream);

    AddImageToBody("image.png", wpd_Doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(ip_Part));

    AppendText("Here is a test bulleted list:");

    wpd_Doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

    //Close the document.
    wpd_Doc.Close();
}

private void AddImageToBody(string s_ImagePath, string s_RelationshipId)
{
    //OpenXmlElement oxe_Element = new Numbering();
    Drawing d_Drawing = new Drawing();
    DrawWord.Inline i_Inline = new DrawWord.Inline();
    DrawWord.Extent e_Extent = new DrawWord.Extent();
    e_Extent.Cx = 600075; //63px / 96dpi * 914400
    e_Extent.Cy = 600075; //63px / 96dpi * 914400
    i_Inline.Extent = e_Extent;

    DrawWord.DocProperties dp_Prop = new DrawWord.DocProperties();
    //dp_Prop.Id = uint.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
    dp_Prop.Id = 1;
    dp_Prop.Name = "Picture 1";
    dp_Prop.Description = "An automated image.";
    i_Inline.DocProperties = dp_Prop;

    DrawWord.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nvgfdp_Prop = new DrawWord.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties();
    Draw.GraphicFrameLocks gfl_Locks = new Draw.GraphicFrameLocks();
    gfl_Locks.NoChangeAspect = true;
    nvgfdp_Prop.GraphicFrameLocks = gfl_Locks;
    i_Inline.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties = nvgfdp_Prop;

    Draw.Graphic g_Graphic = new Draw.Graphic();
    Draw.GraphicData gd_Data = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.GraphicData();
    gd_Data.Uri = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
    DrawPic.Picture p_Pic = new DrawPic.Picture();
    DrawPic.NonVisualPictureProperties nvpp_Prop = new DrawPic.NonVisualPictureProperties();
    DrawPic.NonVisualDrawingProperties nvdp_Prop = new DrawPic.NonVisualDrawingProperties();
    nvdp_Prop.Id = uint.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
    //nvdp_Prop.Name = s_ImagePath;
    nvdp_Prop.Name = "New_Image.png";
    nvpp_Prop.NonVisualDrawingProperties = nvdp_Prop;

    DrawPic.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nvpdp_Prop = new DrawPic.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
    nvpp_Prop.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = nvpdp_Prop;
    p_Pic.NonVisualPictureProperties = nvpp_Prop;

    DrawPic.BlipFill bf_Fill = new DrawPic.BlipFill();
    Draw.Blip b_Blip = new Draw.Blip();
    Draw.ExtensionList el_List = new Draw.ExtensionList();
    Draw.BlipExtension be_Extension = new Draw.BlipExtension();
    be_Extension.Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}";
    el_List.Append(be_Extension);
    b_Blip.Append(el_List);
    b_Blip.Embed = s_RelationshipId;
    b_Blip.CompressionState = Draw.BlipCompressionValues.Print;
    bf_Fill.Blip = b_Blip;

    Draw.Stretch s_Stretch = new Draw.Stretch();
    Draw.FillRectangle fr_Rect = new Draw.FillRectangle();
    s_Stretch.FillRectangle = fr_Rect;
    bf_Fill.Append(s_Stretch);
    p_Pic.BlipFill = bf_Fill;

    DrawPic.ShapeProperties sp_Prop = new DrawPic.ShapeProperties();
    Draw.Transform2D t2d_Transform = new Draw.Transform2D();
    Draw.Offset o_Offset = new Draw.Offset();

    o_Offset.X = 0;
    o_Offset.Y = 0;
    t2d_Transform.Offset = o_Offset;

    Draw.Extents e_Extents = new Draw.Extents();
    e_Extents.Cx = 600075; //63px / 96dpi * 914400
    e_Extents.Cy = 600075; //63px / 96dpi * 914400
    t2d_Transform.Extents = e_Extents;
    sp_Prop.Transform2D = t2d_Transform;

    Draw.PresetGeometry pg_Geom = new Draw.PresetGeometry();
    Draw.AdjustValueList avl_List = new Draw.AdjustValueList();
    pg_Geom.AdjustValueList = avl_List;
    pg_Geom.Preset = Draw.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle;
    sp_Prop.Append(pg_Geom);
    p_Pic.ShapeProperties = sp_Prop;
    gd_Data.Append(p_Pic);
    g_Graphic.GraphicData = gd_Data;
    i_Inline.Graphic = g_Graphic;
    d_Drawing.Inline = i_Inline;
    //oxe_Element.Append(d_Drawing);
    //Run r_Run = new Run(d_Drawing);
    wpd_Doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(d_Drawing)));
}
```

(The variable names are bad, but this was just a test program, so I did not spend too much time. Also, I have the lines spaced to mimic the Xml format that MSDN had in its example. If I could use the C# 3.0 syntax, I would, but I am using Visual Studio 2005.)

Comment: It's unlikely that your problems have anything to do with the version of C#. It's more likely due to the version of .NET.

Comment: What I meant by my statement was that I may have screwed up some of the tree that id built with this code because the syntax is so different with the addition of Collection Initializing in C# 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Surprisingly, I did not find this webpage--because it was some Google pages down with some odd keyword searching--that completely worked: http://blog.stuartwhiteford.com/?p=33. Though it is written with Collection Initializations, I was able to change them to fit C# 2.0 standards.